# Google cloud bigquery php client library return an error?

Tags: php, laravel-5, google-bigquery

> ServiceException in RequestWrapper.php line 257:
>   count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Below is code that is written by me in laravel 5.

```
use Google\Cloud\BigQuery\BigQueryClient;
use Google\Cloud\Core\ServiceBuilder;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->getservicekey = env('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS');
}
//Function where i write code for getting data from gcloud bigquery
public function index()
{
    // Authenticate using Service Account Key
    $cloud = new ServiceBuilder([
        'keyFilePath' => $this->getservicekey
    ]);

    $bigQuery = $cloud->bigQuery();

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM [publicdata:wikipedia.samples] limit 10';

    $queryJobConfig = $bigQuery->query($query);
    $queryResults = $bigQuery->runQuery($queryJobConfig);
    foreach ($queryResults->rows() as $row) {
        print_r($row);
    }
}
```

Below is the image file to show error in detail.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I ran the code snippet you provided and wasn't able to come up with the same error you saw. Would you be able to share your version of PHP and the version of the BigQuery client library you are using? Hopefully I can help debug from there, as that error isn't very helpful.

The error I did get on my end, however, was in regards to formatting.

The first item of note is that the client library utilizes the standard SQL format by default, while your query utilizes the legacy format. Additionally, the FROM clause expects the following format:

```
[project_name:datasetId.tableId]
```

If you update your code to:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM [publicdata:samples.wikipedia] limit 10';
$queryJobConfig = $bigQuery->query($query)
    ->useLegacySql(true);
```

I suspect you should start to get some results.

Comment: I am using this library in laravel. I already mentioned in the question.

Comment: I asked which version of the BigQuery client library you are using, not laravel.

Comment: @HassanRaza did you change your code according to this helpful answer? You have more official info about that here: https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.62.0/bigquery/bigqueryclient?method=query